# Bug or feature? On multiple displays, window split across them is cut off

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, osx-mavericks

Just wondering if anyone knows for sure:

Is this a bug or a feature? When I drag a window between two monitors, it only displays on whichever monitor my mouse pointer is on when I stop dragging (note that it DOES display a low-opacity version on the screen that it is going to be hidden on until I release the button at which point it disappears)...

I feel like it's a feature but I'm hoping it's actually a bug that someone has found a fix for (or that there's a setting for it that is eluding me). I haven't been able to find any information on this so my apologies if it's a silly question.

I'm running OS X Mavericks release 13A598 (GM seed) so that sort of says to me it probably is a feature. I don't know whether to file a bug report or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug, according to [MacRumors](http://www.macrumors.com/roundup/os-x/) in their roundup article on OS X Mavericks:

> Both windowed and full screen apps can also be dragged from one display to the next, but application windows can no longer span multiple monitors.

This seems to be in line with the opacity effect when dragging a window you describe.

Answer (score 5):

Thank goodness it's not a feature that can't be removed.  We were very distressed by not being able to span an application window across screens.  And one of us was not happy about the menu showing up on top of both screens.

I am curious about this now.  I might like the new feature.  But for my friend... taking it back to old-style is what she wants.

In System Settings, choose Mission Control.  Default is "Displays Have Separate Spaces" checked.  Uncheck it and re-log-in or reboot.  You will be able to span windows across multiple screens again.

Comment: This was annoying me.  Found this question then ready your comment.  Useful to know how turn it off, but after thinking about it a bit, it's rare that I'd need/want this functionality (single window spanning windows).  I think I kind of like the new behavior.

Comment: This is very annoying. A screencast from someone with a large monitor could not span two screens and appeared minuscule. I wish Apple didn't try to transform the Mac into a giant iPod.